# SQLite: retrieving columns from two parent tables with JOIN

Tags: join, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have two parent tables which reference foreign keys in a junction table:

```
schoolA_courses (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
course_prefix TEXT, 
course_number INTEGER, 
course_title TEXT

schoolB_courses (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
course_prefix TEXT, 
course_number INTEGER, 
course_title TEXT, 
course_url TEXT)

schoolB_equivalencies (
equivalency_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
schoolA_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
schoolB_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
is_archived INTEGER NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (schoolA_id) REFERENCES schoolA_courses (id), 
FOREIGN KEY (schoolB_id) REFERENCES schoolB_courses (id), 
UNIQUE (schoolA_id, schoolB_id) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)
```

I'm trying to SELECT all columns from the matched rows in both parent tables, but my query only returns-

```
schoolB_courses.course_prefix,
schoolB_courses.course_number,
schoolB_courses.course_title,
schoolB_courses.course_url
```

-from one parent table (schoolB). How can I modify my query to retrieve the specified fields from BOTH tables, e.g.

```
schoolA_courses.course_prefix,
schoolA_courses.course_number,
schoolA_courses.course_title,
schoolB_courses.course_prefix,
schoolB_courses.course_number,
schoolB_courses.course_title,
schoolB_courses.course_url
```

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT 
    schoolA_courses.course_prefix,
    schoolA_courses.course_number,
    schoolA_courses.course_title,
    schoolB_courses.course_prefix,
    schoolB_courses.course_number,
    schoolB_courses.course_title,
    schoolB_courses.course_url
FROM schoolB_equivalencies
INNER JOIN schoolA_courses
ON schoolA_courses.id = schoolB_equivalencies.schoolA_id
INNER JOIN schoolB_courses
ON schoolB_courses.id = schoolB_equivalencies.schoolB_id');
```

The results of the query are

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'course_prefix' => string 'ARCH' (length=4)
      'course_number' => string '111' (length=3)
      'course_title' => string 'Introduction to Structures' (length=26)
      'course_url' => string 'www.google.com' (length=14)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'course_prefix' => string 'ARCH' (length=4)
      'course_number' => string '111' (length=3)
      'course_title' => string 'Introduction to Structures' (length=26)
      'course_url' => string 'www.google.com' (length=14)
```

Comment: And what are the values in the first three columns of the result?

Comment: The query is returning the values for schoolB_courses.course_prefix,
schoolB_courses.course_number, schoolB_courses.course_title, and schoolB_courses.course_url, but is not returning the values for the schoolA tables.

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: The values in all of the columns are strings, except for the id columns - is that what you're asking?

Comment: What I'm asking is what the values of the strings in the first three columns of the query's result are.

Comment: I understand - I've edited the questions with the query results and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language that you're using to access the database (whatever it is) does not allow accessing columns by their index, and gets confused by the identical column names.

Rename the result columns with AS:

```
SELECT 
    schoolA_courses.course_prefix AS A_prefix,
    schoolA_courses.course_number AS A_number,
    schoolA_courses.course_title  AS A_title,
    schoolB_courses.course_prefix AS B_prefix,
    ...
```